# Using an ID of a combobox selection to insert it into another table in C#

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C#, but doing some experiments on my own. I created a Database with 3 tables:

> **tbl_Student**: IDCard, Sname, Ssurname
>
> **tbl_Course**: CID, Cname
>
> **tbl_StudentClass**: CID, IDCard.

There is a relationship between them. Database part I'm OK.

Now I created 2 forms. 1 Form fills the Course table. The other Form fills the Student table.  In the Student Form, I have a combobox that lists the CourseName, reading from the Course Table.  The Combobox is working fine.

The problem is that when I want to click the SAVE button, the StudentCourse table is filled using the IDCard and the CID according to what course the user choose from the combobox dropdown. I can fill the IDCard but don't know how to fill the CID, that is use the CID of the Course Name selected from the combobox....any help please?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace StudentClassApplication
{
    public partial class frmCreateStudent : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=REUBEN-PC\MSSQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StudentClass;Integrated Security=True");

        public frmCreateStudent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillCombobox();
        }

        private void SaveStudent_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT into tbl_Student (IDCard,Sname, Ssurname) values (@IDCard,@Sname,@Ssurname)", con);

                //insert data into tbl_Student Table
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDCard", textBox1.Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sname", textBox2.Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ssurname", textBox3.Text);
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd1.Parameters.Clear();

                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT  into tbl_StudentClass (IDCard, CID) VALUES (@IDCard,@CID)", con);

                //insert data into tbl_StudentClass Table
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDCard", textBox1.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd2.Parameters.Clear();

                con.Close(); //connection close here , that is disconnected from data source
                MessageBox.Show("Student has been added ! ");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot open connection ! ");
            }
        }

        private void frmCreateStudent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void FillCombobox()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            cmd.CommandText = ("select * from tbl_Class");

            SqlDataReader myreader;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    string cname = myreader.GetString(1);
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(cname);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot open connection ! ");
            }
        }

        protected void comboBox1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var value = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are yet studying and experimenting, I'd highly recommend you to try [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/getting-started). It make you to avoid all those SQL query made by hand, and adds extra check (like SQL-Injection issues, null values handling, etc). Now let me try to see a solution for your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `tbl_Course` and a Form for courses, so I guess you have a class like:

```
class Course
{
    public int CID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, instead of filling the `ComboBox` just with the names of the courses, fill it with entire `Course` objects!

Something like this in the constructor:

```
comboBox.DataSource = GetCourses();
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

where `GetCourses()` is similar to your `FillCombobox()` method:

```
private List<Course> GetCourses()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from tbl_Class";
    };

    List<Course> courses = new List<Course>();
    SqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            Course c = new Course
            {
                CID = myreader.GetInt32(0),
                name = myreader.GetString(1)
            };
            courses.Add(c);
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot open connection!");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con != null)
            con.Close();
    }

    return courses;
}
```

Then, in `SaveStudent_button1_Click()` change this line:

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
```

in this way:

```
Course c = (Course)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", c.CID);
```